# Stop Emacs from adding all subdirs to default-directory

Tags: package, directories, start-up

I'm having trouble stopping Emacs from loading all packages in my `default-directory`. When I call `c-h v load-packages` I get a listing of all subdirectories inside my elpa directory, which I want to avoid.

I have the following in my startup files:

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
```

and I do **not** have the following:

```
(let ((default-directory user-emacs-directory))
  (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)
  )
```

(I have it commented, though).

In spite of that, I still get the following when I ask Emacs to show me the value of `load-path`:

```
 ("/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/adaptive-wrap-0.5/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/async-20150818.1154/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/auctex-11.88.8/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/autopair-20140825.427/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/color-theme-20080305.34/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/dedicated-20090428.1231/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/dired+-20150830.1456/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/duplicate-thing-20120515.948/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/expand-region-20150902.558/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/flx-ido-20140821.2033/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/flx-20140921.739/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/flycheck-20150831.1343/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/highlight-parentheses-20150421.2328/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/hl-indent-20141227.1330/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/hl-line+-20150104.2222/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/hl-sentence-20140802.920/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/ido-hacks-20150331.1209/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/ido-ubiquitous-20150630.926/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/ido-completing-read+-20150630.926/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/indent-guide-20150713.2327/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/leuven-theme-20150818.556/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/lua-mode-20150804.2302/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/markdown-mode+-20120829.510/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/markdown-mode-20150904.656/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/mc-extras-20150218.234/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/move-text-20140307.1644/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/multi-term-20150220.1320/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/multiple-cursors-20150710.456/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/neotree-20150904.609/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/paradox-20150812.732/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/let-alist-1.0.4/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/pkg-info-20150517.443/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/epl-20150517.433/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/pretty-mode-20141207.1152/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/rainbow-delimiters-20150320.17/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/second-sel-20150105.46/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/seq-20150709.1040/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/smart-mode-line-20150803.338/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/rich-minority-20150305.516/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/smartparens-20150813.1451/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/dash-20150829.433/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/spinner-1.4/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/tabbar-20141109.143/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/undo-tree-20140509.522/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/use-package-20150817.2257/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/diminish-20091203.1012/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/bind-key-20150321.213/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/volatile-highlights-20141004.2240/" "/Users/nivaca/Dropbox/emacs/elpa/yasnippet-20150811.1222/")
```

Ultimately, the issue at hand is that I don't want Emacs to automatically load `AuCTeX` (I have eliminated all references to it from my startup files, but it still keeps loading itself).

Any ideas on how to stop this?

---

**Update**

Even with no startup file (I removed my `.emacsd` file) I get the same value for `load-path`. This happens even if I start with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Because that's where `package.el` installs all my `elpa` packages.

Comment: `(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)` *is* sufficient (certainly in 24.5) if you're not otherwise causing the issue yourself. Do you have an out-dated byte-compiled version of your init file for which that would-be commented code is actually being evaluated? If not (or if package autoloads are actually being processed), then it sounds like *something* is calling `package-initialize`.

Comment: @phils: "awkward [...to...] treat one package differently to all the others" - actually I think setting `package-load-list` allows this.

Comment: npostavs: Right, it sounds like a value of `'((auctex nil) all)` would do the trick here. (And as such, I've deleted my incorrect comment.)

Comment: @Phils, Well, I really don't know what's causing it. The value of `package-load-list` is nil at run time.

Comment: "This happens even if I start with `emacs -Q`" ... Well that makes no sense at all. So if you run this from your shell: `\emacs -Q --batch --eval "(print (mapconcat 'identity load-path  \"\\n\"))";` the output includes your ELPA package directories?!?

Comment: Yeap. That's my conundrum. See output here: http://pastebin.com/v6RFAits